# Properly setting up a Usage Trigger

Tags: php, twilio

Let's say I would like to set up a trigger that fires every 1000 SMS messages.
When creating a trigger, like the one below from the API docs, how is the "TriggerBy" field reset so that it can trigger for the next 1000?

```
<?php
// Get the PHP helper library from twilio.com/docs/php/install
require_once('/path/to/twilio-php/Services/Twilio.php'); // Loads the library

// Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
$sid = "AC828da6a8765c3edaf2727d241dc68b87"; 
$token = "{{ auth_token }}"; 
$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);

$trigger = $client->account->usage_triggers->create("sms", "1000", "http://www.example.com/", array());
echo $trigger->sid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio Developer Evangelist here.

If you want to your trigger to be recurring you can use the following code:

```
$trigger = $client->account->usage_triggers->create("sms", "1000", "http://example.com", array("Recurring"=>"daily"));
```

This will notify you each day when you hit 1000 SMS messages. If you'd like to receive notifications in an period shorter than daily you'll have to set a Alert Trigger for each increment (1000, 2000, 3000, 4000).

Hope that helps!